# react swipe card failed to compile

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-swipeable-views

Im working on a project where im creating swipe card effect and im getting failed to compile when running `npm run start:dev` on the app

```js
import React from 'react';
import Cards, { Card } from 'react-swipe-card'


const data = ['Alexandre', 'Thomas', 'Lucien']

const SwipeCard = () => (
  return (
      <Cards onEnd={action('end')} className='master-root'>
        {data.map(item => 
          <Card 
            onSwipeLeft={action('swipe left')} 
            onSwipeRight={action('swipe right')}>
            <h2>{item}</h2>
          </Card>
        )}
      </Cards>
  )
);

export default SwipeCard;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Doc can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-swipe-card#usage)

Comment: are you transpiling your code ? If yes, please attached babelrc, package.json and your build tool file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an arrow function without a body for your `SwipeCard` component which has an implicit return, so you can just remove the `return` statement.

```
const SwipeCard = () => (
  <Cards onEnd={action("end")} className="master-root">
    {data.map(item => (
      <Card
        key={item}
        onSwipeLeft={action("swipe left")}
        onSwipeRight={action("swipe right")}
      >
        <h2>{item}</h2>
      </Card>
    ))}
  </Cards>
);
```

Comment: i did that and now im getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: action is not defined error`

Comment: @toymoy Where does `action` come from in your code. You most likely have to define or import it from somewhere.

Comment: if you see on the second line `<Cards onEnd={action("end")} className="master-root">` action is called. I did not change anything. its the same code as the documentaion

Comment: @toymoy Yes, I an see `action` in your code. but where do you get it from? It is not imported or initialized anywhere. It is not defined, like your error says.

Comment: i see what you mean. i havent defined action function and not sure how i should do that either as it is not mentioned on the documentation.

Comment: any suggestions on that

Comment: @toymoy I think it's just an example. You could write `onSwipeLeft={() => console.log("swipe left")}` as a first test and go from there if you need some extra logic when the user swipes.

Comment: i made `action` function with console.log(value) and takes value as argument. this time im getting `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: @toymoy Look at the `key` prop in my answer. [This is a good read on the subject](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: im so thankful for your help. It is still not working tho. is there any resource u would point out to me to get this running.

Comment: this time im getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null`

Comment: @toymoy You're welcome! I'm not sure what might be wrong. [It only seems to work in React 15 in my port of the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/yprp40vj3x).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Tholle you can simply remove the return statement. Alternatively you can change the outer `(` and `)` to `{` and `}` as shown below to imply a function. I generally do this to have a consistent format across all my arrow functions.

```
import React from 'react';
import Cards, { Card } from 'react-swipe-card'


const data = ['Alexandre', 'Thomas', 'Lucien']

const SwipeCard = () => {
  return (
      <Cards onEnd={action('end')} className='master-root'>
        {data.map(item => 
          <Card 
            onSwipeLeft={action('swipe left')} 
            onSwipeRight={action('swipe right')}>
            <h2>{item}</h2>
          </Card>
        )}
      </Cards>
  )
};

export default SwipeCard;
```

Comment: i did that and now im getting Uncaught ReferenceError: action is not defined error